# Windows: Get start and end of .text section

Tags: c++, windows, portable-executable

I can succesfully retrieve the base address of a module loaded in my process by executing:

```
MODULEINFO mInfo;
GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(),GetModuleHandle(L"moduleName"),&mInfo,sizeof(mInfo));
LPVOID baseAddress = mInfo.lpBaseOfDll;
```

But how can one now retrieve the start and end address of the `.text` section of that module?

Comment: You haven't explained why mInfo.SizeOfImage doesn't meet your needs.  Consider VirtualQuery(), pass baseAddress.

Comment: I actually just want to go through the memory space of the .text section (where the actually code is) and not through the whole module space. How can one use VirtualQuery to obtain the start address of the .text section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications and modules (aka. any executable code) is built based on the so-called "[Portable Executable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)" format specified by Microsoft. In order to retrieve the information you want, you must go through the logical tables in memory and, based on the PE format, access the desired members. Sections host data and code. In order to retrieve the begin and the end of a section (e.g. .text) you must inspect the Sections Headers and retrieve whether or not it is executable. [Matt Pietrek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) has written the standard documents that must be considered as "the" introduction into PE.

Comment: To control your findings, you can always use WinDbg, OllyDbg, etc.. These tools show the sections, their types, begin address, end address, etc.